# Why does the "System" process have my BCD open?

Tags: windows-7, bcd

I discovered this when I tried to use EasyBCD to well, edit by bcd, but it said "The current file is in use and cannot be opened by EasyBCD..."

So I tried to use handle.exe to stop it but it said

```
\Handle>handle -c 15C -p 4

Handle v3.46
Copyright (C) 1997-2011 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

  15C: File  (---)   C:\Boot\BCD
Close handle 15C in System (PID 4)? (y/n) y
Error closing handle:
The handle is invalid.
```

Why does system have my bcd open and how can i stop it? I have tried rebooting and googling.

Comment: I also have this same issue, please help us.

Comment: Well I kindof solved it by deploying a bcd to a thumdrive, then booting off the thumdrive. System will then hold the bcd on the thumdrive, and not the bcd on your hd. Safety remove will fail but System will not hold the bcd on your hdd if you manually remove the thumdrive. Still want to know why System does this.

Comment: I have just physically unplugged the USB drive dirty style and lets see tomorrow how it went.

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably is you've run handle as a normal user. If you read the [following section](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle#installation), it says:

> You run Handle by typing "handle". You must have administrative
>   privilege to run Handle.